# Circular Left Rotation Algorithm in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, bit-shift

SO I have this algorithm that does left rotation

```
    public static ushort RotateLeft(ushort value, int count)
    {
        int left = value << count;
        int right = value >> (16 - count);
        return (ushort)(left | right);
    }
```

However this is not producing the values I want for example if I have a value of 18 when rotated left by 1 bit it the result should be 3 but instead this just adds a zero at the end:

This is what the algorithm does:

```
10010     18
100100    36
```

This is what I want:

```
10010     18
00101      3
```

The bits should be shifted out of the sign bit position (bit 0) enter the least significant bit position (bit 15) and, consequently, no bits are lost.

What I want is described here:
http://www.xgc.com/manuals/m1750-ada/m1750/x2733.html

It's a CRC algorithm that I want to convert to C#

Comment: A ushort is 16 bits, not 5.. your algorithm is shifting `0000000000010010` to `0000000000100100`; which is correct.

Comment: @Blorgbeard You are correct, now that I think of it I would like to discard all the zeros on the left and then do the rotation, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You'll need to find the most-significant '1' bit, then change your shift algorithm to rotate through that many bits instead of 16.

Comment: In your example, you show binary for 5, but you say you want the value of 3. Which one is correct?  Also, just to be clear: if you start with 18 (10010b), you want the next values to be 5 (101b), then 3 (11b), then 3 for the rest of as many iterations as anyone ever does. That seems really weird. Are you sure that's the operation you want?

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is what I want: http://www.xgc.com/manuals/m1750-ada/m1750/x2733.html

Comment: @EricBergman that's what you've got, and not what you're describing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be corrected as follows.

I add new argument 'numberOfBits' to presents number of bits to be rotated.

```
public static ushort RotateLeft(ushort value, int numberOfBits int countToRotate)
{
    countToRotate = countToRotate mod numberOfBits; // in case of rotate more than once.
    ushort mask = -1  // 1s for all 16 bits.
    mask = mask << numberOfBits;

    int left = value << countToRotate;  // rotate left
    int right = left >> (numberOfBits); // move left-overflowed bits to right
    return (ushort)((left | right) & mask);
}
```

This code works correctly if (numOfBits+countToRotate)<=16.

Comment: +1. And if you need to determine the `numberOfBits` value, see https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious and the three or four techniques that follow.

Answer (score 0):

```
(x << n) | (x >> (<bit size> - n))
```

Should give you the appropriate shift, which is what your function is doing.